# What are the bare minimum metrics to use in Performance Monitor with SharePoint 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-server, metrics

I need to assemble a list of metrics to publish for [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/overview/), for SharePoint performance monitoring using [PowerShell Prometheus Exporter](https://github.com/jobec/powershell-prom-client).

The Big Four is a no brainer ([Bradley Schach - Collecting Server Performance Metrics: PowerShell](https://bradleyschacht.com/collecting-server-performance-metrics-powershell/)), but what about the rest?

I know about several commercial tools, but I need to put the monitoring in the same montoring tool used for all our other systems at the company.

Microsoft doesn't seem to have a good page for this and I can't find any recommendations or best practice anywhere on Internet :/

The cmdlet `Get-SPDiagnosticsPerformanceCounter` will get me a list from each server what SharePoint is currently using itself. But I need a little bit more than that...